# Exception: Invalid_argument "index out of bounds"

Tags: arrays, ocaml

I wrote the following:

```
type slidingTile = { 
  mutable mat: char array array; 
  mutable row: int; 
  mutable column: int
};;

let a = {
  mat=[|
    [|'1'; '2'; '3'|];
    [|'4'; '5'; '6'|];
    [|'7'; '8'; '9'|]
  |]; 
  row=3;
  column=3
};;

let slide tile i j =
  let copy mat = 
    let mat1 = Array.make_matrix (Array.length mat) (Array.length mat.(0)) mat.(0).(0) in
    for i=0 to Array.length mat do
      for j=0 to Array.length mat.(0) do
        mat1.(i).(j)<- mat.(i).(j)
      done; 
    done; 
    mat1 
  in
  let mat1 = copy tile.mat in
  if (i > Array.length tile.mat) || (j > Array.length tile.mat.(0)) then
    tile
  else if (i = tile.row + 1 && j = tile.column) || 
          (i = tile.row - 1 && j = tile.column) || 
          (i = tile.row && j = tile.column + 1) || 
          (i = tile.row && j = tile.column - 1) then
    (mat1.(i-1).(j-1) <- tile.mat.(tile.row-1).(tile.column-1);
     mat1.(tile.row-1).(tile.column-1) <- tile.mat.(i-1).(j-1);
     tile.mat <- mat1;
     tile.row <- i;
     tile.column <- j;
     tile)
  else 
    tile;;
```

This code works OK, but when I call `slide a 2 2;;` I get message `Exception: Invalid_argument "index out of bounds"`. I have never seen this kind of messages. What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that you have accessed an array with an index that is either less than 0 or >= the size of the array. I.e., an out-of-bounds index.

```
# let a = Array.make 10 0;;
val a : int array = [|0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0|]
# a.(-1);;
Exception: Invalid_argument "index out of bounds".
# a.(10);;
Exception: Invalid_argument "index out of bounds".
# a.(4);;
- : int = 0
```

(If you want more help with your code you should format it so that it's a little more readable.)

Comment: It isn't to help us that you want to format your code well. It's to help _yourself_. The [OCaml Programming Guidelines](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/guidelines.html) are your friend. You would also be well-advised to break your code down into small, easy to reason about chunks. For instance, maybe you want a `move` function that takes a set of tile coordinates and "moves" it to another set of coordinates. You can write that, make sure it works robustly, and then not have to worry about that again.